# how to avoid circular dependency between tables

Tags: database-design

i am designing online test application, where users login, take exams and see the score. it is obvious , we need to have question and answer table

and my design concludes below

```
QUESTION 
--------
ID
ANSWER_ID (ANSWER FOR THIS QUESTION)
TEXT
:

ANSWER

ID
TEXT
QUESTION_ID
```

for eg:- question has 4 options, so four answer rows which will have same question id. and question table will have the actual answer_id (above 4)

attached diagram [image]

but in above case, it has circular dependency which i feel will create problems when i user database frameworks like hibernate to handle the data. looking for any alternative design for above requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask yourself, what is the relation between the two tables? Can a question have multiple answers? And can an answer have multiple questions? If yes, you have a m:n relationship. If you answered only the first question with yes, you have a 1:n relationship.

If you have a `1:n relationship`, you don't need the `answer_id` in your `question` table. Joining will just work like

```
...
FROM question q
JOIN answer a ON q.question_id = a.question_id
...
```

If you have a `m:n relationship`, you need a third table that resolves the relation (it's called a junction table, or bridge table).

**Tables:**

question (question_id)
answer (answer_id)
question_2_answer (question_id, answer_id)

**Join:**

```
...
FROM question q
JOIN question_2_answer q2a ON q.question_id = q2a.question_id
JOIN answer a ON a.answer_id = q2a.answer_id
...
```

---

BTW, you won't need `BIGINT` as datatype, simply `INT` will do, or will you have more than 2147483647 questions/answers?

- read more about [datatypes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: incase of 1st scenario.. how would i know which option is answer for a question?

Comment: Exactly like I joined in my answer. There's no "other way round joining". Join the tables like I did, that's it. Or I don't understand your question.

Comment: If you wonder then, for example how to get questions that have no answers (with my join you would get an empty result (just `join` is equivalent to `inner join`), [here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)'s a nice explanation of different joins.

Comment: question has 4 (4 rows of answer )options (among 1 will be answer), but all options will have same question_id, but how do i know that option 1 is correct answer for question??

Comment: How should I know? You have to store this somewhere in your data of course. An additional column in your answer table would do, like is_correct_answer, datatype tinyint, with 0 representing no and 1 representing yes.

Comment: but that take unnecessary memory for the sake of marking option as answer?, so i added answer_id in question table, but to avoid circular dependency, this could be better option

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. Imagine you want to get just the correct answers to all questions. With your design, you would have to get all answers or you would have to remember, that you suddenly have to join over an entirely different field. With my design, you just join as usual and add `WHERE answer.is_correct_answer = 1`.

Comment: And for your unnecessary memory comment, see the additional hint I placed in the answer. Plus, you can also have an entry set to `NULL` when it's not the correct answer.

Comment: This solution is wrong... its a 1:n relationship. See my answer below